# Pandas fill dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe, the **date** corresponds to quarterly periods and the **amount** (and other additional columns not shown here for simplification) corresponding to the associated **id** grouping. Dates are unique per id.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan
d = {'id': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'date': ['2020-09-30', '2020-06-30', '2020-03-31', 
'2020-09-30', '2020-06-30'], 'amount': [1, 2, nan , 5, nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df
     id        date       amount
0     a     2020-09-30       1
1     a     2020-06-30       2
2     a     2020-03-31       
3     b     2020-09-30       5
4     b     2020-06-30
```

I would like to extend the period of time that the quarters start by a set start quarter date in the past so that the quarter periods start and exist for the same dates for each id. In this example the data should start at `2019-12-31` and any quarters in between should be filled in if the row is missing.

I would like to backfill the missing values (such as amount) based on the most recent present value.

The output would look like this:

```
     id        date       amount
     a     2020-09-30       1
     a     2020-06-30       2
     a     2020-03-31       2
     a     2019-12-31       2
     b     2020-09-30       5
     b     2020-06-30       5
     b     2020-03-31       5     
     b     2019-12-31       5
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: next time, please properly format your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define a new time range every third month starting from 2019-12-31 and reindex your dataframe. Then fill the `NaN` values with a backward fill `bfill` method. See code below with comments.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the DataFrame according to your question
d = {'id': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'date': ['2020-09-30', '2020-06-30', '2020-03-31', 
'2020-09-30', '2020-06-30'], 'amount': [1, 2, None, 5, None]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Transform date to datetime column
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
# Set multiindex to (id, date) as they are the "unique keys" of your amount values
df.set_index(['id', 'date'], inplace=True)

# Define new period for the datetime index (every 3 months)
index = pd.date_range('2019-12-31', '2020-09-30', freq='3M')

# Reindex the Dataframe and fill NaNs with a backward method
print(df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.get_level_values(0).unique(), index])).fillna(method='bfill'))


# Output
#                amount
# id                   
# a  2019-12-31     2.0
#    2020-03-31     2.0
#    2020-06-30     2.0
#    2020-09-30     1.0
# b  2019-12-31     5.0
#    2020-03-31     5.0
#    2020-06-30     5.0
#    2020-09-30     5.0
```

**Note**: Setting the multiindex including the `id` column is needed as you want to resample your date without merging `id` values `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

The [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) offers an abstraction for exposing missing rows:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# create a mapping of the new dates
# reusing @scandav's index variable
index = pd.date_range('2019-12-31', '2020-09-30', freq='3M')
index = dict(date = index)
(df.complete('id', index)
   .sort_values(['id', 'date'], ascending = [True, False])
   .ffill(downcast = 'infer')
) 
  id       date  amount
0  a 2020-09-30       1
1  a 2020-06-30       2
2  a 2020-03-31       2
5  a 2019-12-31       2
3  b 2020-09-30       5
4  b 2020-06-30       5
7  b 2020-03-31       5
6  b 2019-12-31       5
```